# Finding Maximum values in each column of dataframe subset to year, with output showing which week in the year the maximum occurs

Tags: r, max, unique, subset

Here's a small sample of my data:

```
| Year | week | Var1 | Var2 |   
|------|------|------|------|   
| 1990 | 2    | 60   | 70   |   
| 1992 | 1    | 50   | 100  |   
| 1992 | 2    | 60   | 80   |
```

My real data have 50 variables, 20 years and every week of each year. I want to find the maximum value in each column, but I need to know which week it occurs.

The desired output is a table "mymaxdata", containing the week when the data is at its highest. e.g year 1992 week var 1 would week2, var2 would be week 1.

I have tried using `dplyr` package, but can only obtain the maximum value in each variable, not the week in which it happened in the year. 
I can do it manually per year, then looking up the corrsponding output to find the week, using the following code.

```
which.max( mydata[ mydata[ , "year"] == 1990 , "var1" ] ) 
which.max( mydata[ mydata[ , "year"] == 1990 , "var2" ] ) 
which.max( mydata[ mydata[ , "year"] == 1992 , "var1" ] )
```

However, given the large number of variables in my real data, I want to find a more efficient way to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

#mydf <- data.frame(Year = c(1990, 1992,1992),
#                   Week = c(2,1,2),
#                   Var1 = c(60,50,60),
#                   Var2 = c(70,100,80))

melt(mydf, id.vars = c("Year", "Week")) %>%
        group_by(Year, variable) %>%
        summarise(Max = paste0("Week", Week[which(value==max(value))], 
                                                       collapse = ", ")) %>%
        do(dcast(.,formula = Year~variable, value.var = 'Max'))

#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#Groups: Year [2]
#
#   Year  Var1  Var2
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1  1990 Week2 Week2
#2  1992 Week2 Week1
```

Comment: Thanks. Works in your sample but I get the following error message:Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : expecting a single value

Comment: It's possible if you have the same values for let's say `Var1` in both `Week1` and `Week2`. In this case `Week[which(value==max(value))]` returns two-values vector `c(Week1, Week2)` which leads to the error.

Comment: Try `paste0("Week", Week[which(value==max(value))], collapse = ", ")` under the `summarise` line.

Comment: Sadly not! Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : expecting a single value.

Comment: My fault, I put the `collapse = ", " outside the `paste0` call. Try to change the `summarise` line as below:
`summarise(Max = paste0("Week", Week[which(value==max(value))], 
            collapse = ", ")) `

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(1990, 1992, 1992), week = c(2, 1, 2), Var1 = c(60, 50, 60), Var2 = c(70, 100, 80))

apply(df[,3:4], 2, FUN=function(data){
    return(c(max(data), df[which.max(data), "week"]))
})
```

Output:

```
     Var1 Var2
[1,]   60  100
[2,]    2    1
```

Where the `row 1` is the max value and `row 2` is the week

---

**Even nicer:**

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(1990, 1992, 1992), week = c(2, 1, 2), Var1 = c(60, 50, 60), Var2 = c(70, 100, 80))

a <- apply(df[,3:4], 2, FUN=function(data){
    return(c(max(data), df[which.max(data), "week"]))
})

rownames(a)  <- c("MAX", "WEEK")
a <- t(a)
a
```

Output:

```
     MAX WEEK
Var1  60    2
Var2 100    1
```

---

**Explanation:**

First the example data frame is created:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(1990, 1992, 1992), week = c(2, 1, 2), Var1 = c(60, 50, 60), Var2 = c(70, 100, 80))
```

The `apply` function execute the function `FUN` for every column specified in first argument (in this case only de columns with Var).

The parameter `data` in `FUN` will be the current column. This function returns a vector with the `max` value of  the current column and the week it corresponds.
The code `df[which.max(data), "week"])` returns the week of the max value in the column.

Comment: I have 100's of rows of data. Could you kindly explain how this work with var1=c (60,50,60) retyping my data into var1=c () for 50 variables with 100's of row of data seems error prone and long! For year and week I can put 1990:2016 as that is set and week 1:52.

Comment: @Beccalou The first line of each code suggestion simply creates your example data.frame. You presumably already have df loaded.

Comment: Edited post with explanation.

Comment: @CarlesMitjans Thank you. sorry miss read data part. so that is great but i can't get it subset it by year. It just returns the max over all the years using your code. what i need is the output i have from your code but per year. e.g in 1990, week 3 had the max. in 1992 it was 4.